# Objective function of a Genetic Algorithm

Tags: genetic-algorithms

This is my first effort about AI/ML.

I have the following problem given by my teacher,

> Design a simple genetic algorithm in MATLAB, with binary-coded chromosomes, in
>   order to solve pattern finding problem in 16-bit strings.
>
> The objective function is given by the following formula:
>
> `F(x) =`
>   `NoS("010") + 2NoS("0110") + 3NoS("01110") + 4NoS("011110") +` 
>   `5NoS("0111110") + 6NoS("01111110") + 7NoS("011111110") +`
>   `6NoS("0111111110") +  5NoS("01111111110") + 4NoS("011111111110") +`
>   `3NoS("0111111111110") +  2NoS("01111111111110") +`
>   `NoS("011111111111110")`

I couldn't understand the formula.

What does it mean by Nos?

**What operations are they performing on those binary strings?**

What is `F(x)`?

Comment: `NoS` means "numbers of" (that is, count the occurrences of the substring in the individual's chromosome). `F(x)` is the fitness you are computing (a scalar number), I don't understand your question.

Comment: @lacerbi, What operations are they performing on those binary strings?

Comment: I'll try again. `mNoS("110")` means that you need to count how many `110` patterns there are in your individual's chromosome (string), multiply by `m`, and that's _one_ of the contributions to the fitness of the individual. Sum over all contributions and that's `F(x)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NoS` means "numbers of" (that is, count the occurrences of the substring in the individual's chromosome). `F(x)` is the fitness you are computing (a scalar number).

In particular, `mNoS("110")` where `m` is a scalar, means `m` $\cdot$ `NoS("110")`, that is:

- count how many `110` patterns there are in your individual's chromosome (string `x`);
- multiply by `m`;

and this is *one* of the contributions to the fitness of the individual.
Sum over all contributions and that is your `F(x)`.